# Fire Extinguisher 6 year maintenance

Tags: fire

I have presented fire extinguishers to be tagged to a Florida Fire company.  They indicated that the devices are old and need a 6 year maintenance inspection.  What exactly is tested?

Comment: Have you asked the company?

Comment: I did not because, I sensed I was receiving the "upsell" and would like a neutral third party to comment.  Through this vendor, I would be better of buying a new extinguisher

Comment: I guess my point is, this question is currently very open ended. It may be better if you ask them, and then present their answer here and ask if that is a reasonable things to do to a 6 year old fire extinguisher.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a well documented maintenance procedure. I don't know much about fire extinguishers, but a quick internet search presented the [following information](https://www.guardianfireprotection.com/6-year-maintenance/):

> **Six-Year Maintenance**
>
> Every six years, stored pressure fire extinguishers that require a
> 12-year hydrostatic test (e.g. dry chemical extinguishers) must be
> emptied and proper maintenance procedures performed [see NFPA 10(98),
> Sec. 4-4.3]. The exception to this rule is nonrechargeable
> extinguishers, which are required to be removed from service 12 years
> from the date of manufacture. Again, this maintenance must be
> performed by an approved extinguisher servicing company.

So it seems if the extinguishers are of the type that require a 12 year hydrostatic test, this appears to be a legitimate maintenance requirement. I guess it would also depend on if your locale requires you to follow the above referenced NFPA standard document or not.